# Self Segue & delegate weird behaviour

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, segue

I have created a *Self Segue* from a Button to View Controller itself i.e, when button is clicked the view will go to itself.

I have a `Bool` variable `isSearch` declared in the View Controller:

```
var isSearch! false
```

Now when the button is clicked `prepareForSegue` outputs the `isSearch` value i.e `false`, this is correct:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "SearchSelfSegue" {
            if let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as? SearchVC {
                print("SearchSelfSegue:\(isSearch)")// output: false
            }
        }
    }
```

I have a protocol defined above View Controller:

```
protocol SearchVCDelegate {
    func goBack()
}
```

View Controller conforms to the protocol:

```
class SearchVC: UIViewController,SearchVCDelegate {

    var delegate:SearchVCDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.delegate = self

    }
```

There is Button which will take user back and delegate method will be called:

```
@IBAction func actBack(sender: AnyObject?) {
    print("actBack():\(isSearch)")
    if let _ = delegate {
        delegate?.goBack()
    }
    self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
}
```

And the implemented Delegate method, here I set `isSearch` to `true`,and output is `true`, which is correct:

```
func goBack() {
    isSearch = true
    print("goBack():\(isSearch)")
}
```

*Now when I click back again. The output shows `false`, but I have set it to `true` already.*

The overall output goes like this:

```
SearchSelfSegue:false //I went to next view
actBack():false //clicked back button
goBack():true //delegate method executed
actBack():false //clicked back again, this should be true.
```

Comment: segue is working perfect check for delegate(). IF It is fine then use NSUserDefault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you segue to the same viewController you're actually creating a new instance of that viewController and segueing to that. The way you have set up your delegate is that each view controller will be the delegate of itself so when you click the back button from your second viewController you're changing the `isSearch` variable in that **second** viewController. The `isSearch` from the first viewController won't be changed.

I don't understand why you would want to do this but if you're sure about what you're doing you should set `self` as the `delegate` of the newly created viewController instead of the original one.

To do that, first remove `self.delegate = self` from `viewDidLoad()` method and then modify `prepareForSegue` like this:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SearchSelfSegue" {
        if let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as? SearchVC {
            //Set this viewController as the delegate of the new viewController
            destVC.delegate = self
            print("SearchSelfSegue:\(isSearch)")// output: false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch! The moment I posted this question I figured it out myself. :D , Accepting for future reference.